# htaccess - Map a dynamic path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to show the contents of `http://example.com/about.php` under `http://example.com/seller/samsung/about.php` where samsung is a **dynamic** and **non-existing folder**. I have tried the following code:

`RewriteRule ^seller/([^/]+)/(.*)$ ./$1`

It works when I do it manually like this:

`RewriteRule ^seller/samsung/(.*)$ ./$1`

Comment: Hi @anubhava, I am trying to display the contents of http://example.com/about.php under http://example.com/seller/samsung/about.php using this code: RewriteRule ^seller/([^/]+)/(.*)$ ./$1 where ([^/]+) I believe defines a dynamic path, but it wont work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Should be `[^/]+`  without parenthesis `()`

`RewriteRule ^seller/[^/]+/(.*)$ ./$1`